# MongoDB group documents and combine nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

Right now I have a design such as this:

```
{
    "_id": MongoID,
    "name": "Organization 1",
    "url": "http://url.url",
    people: [] // 20,000 max
},
{
    "_id": MongoID,
    "name": "Organization 1",
    "url": "http://url.url",
    people: [] // a different set of 20,000 max
},
{
    "_id": MongoID,
    "name": "Organization 2",
    "url": "http://url.url",
    people: [] // 20,000 max
}
```

This splitting is done to work aroudn the 16MB document size limitation. I want to aggregate the results to form the following result:

```
{
    "_id": MongoID,
    "name": "Organization 1",
    "url": "http://url.url",
    people: [] // combined 40,000 max people
},
{
    "_id": MongoID,
    "name": "Organization 2",
    "url": "http://url.url",
    people: [] // 20,000 max
}
```

I am querying based on some of the fields in the people subdocuments. Here is the group aggregate I have nwow that currently does not return results. When I did not have split documents, this worked. Now it does not.

```
$search_column_query = array(array("people.search_columns.surname" => "Smith")); // example
$documents_with_results = $db->organization_data->aggregate(array(
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query),
        array( '$unwind' => '$people' ),
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query),
        array( '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$_id',
            'name' => array( '$first' => '$name' ),
            'url' => array( '$first' => '$url' ),
            'people' => array( '$push' => '$people' )
        ))
    ));
```

The goal is to combine all of the split-up documents into a single document with a combined subdocument list of people.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does "not return results" mean to you? Can you explain? You say this worked "before", but I still notably see you are grouping on `_id` and not on "name", which would be the common field between your "split" documents.

Comment: I altered the $group to set the _id to '$name'. I also removed the 'url' just for testing. I still get a result array of 0 length and a response of "ok". array(2) { ["result"]=> array(0) { } ["ok"]=> float(1) }

Comment: The `_id` key in a `$group` statement is what you "group by". So "$name" is what you seem to want there. If "nothing" is coming back then something is likely wrong in your matching and something else has changed other than your "splitting". Show some sample document information that you expect to match.

Comment: You can't  have result documents from aggregation that are larger than 16MBs either.